# Unboundlocal Error Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm writing a blog app with SEO friendly urls.  When I visit an invalid url I get the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'path' referenced before assignment

valid urls work fine.

Here is the code:

```
class ViewPost(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, slug):
        post = Posts.all()
        post.filter('path =', slug)
        results = post.fetch(1)
        for post in results:
            path = post.path
        if path == slug:
            self.render_template('post.html', {'post':post})
        else:
            self.response.out.write('no post with this slug')
```

Here are examples of a [valid](http://busilinks.appspot.com/2012/05/first-post) with no error, and a [invalid](http://busilinks.appspot.com/2012/05/junk) that throws the error.  You can see the complete stack trace on the [invalid](http://busilinks.appspot.com/2012/05/junk) example.

The complete code is on [github](https://github.com/buslinks/myblog/blob/master/views.py) line 62.

Thanks in advance.  I'm new to python so I really appreciate your help and feedback.

**Update**

1. For context, I'm comparing two strings to determine if I have content to serve.
2. What I expect to see: If the slug and path are equal , it should renders the template.  If not equal: It is supposed to respond with 'no post with this slug' message.
3. Other things I've done.

   - I've verified that I get a slug and path value.
   - I've tried changing the idention like this.

This stops me from getting the error, but I don't get my else response.  Instead I get a blank page with nothing in view source.

```
class ViewPost(BaseHandler):
def get(self, slug):
    post = Posts.all()
    post.filter('path =', slug)
    results = post.fetch(1)
    for post in results:
        path = post.path
        if path == slug:
            self.render_template('post.html', {'post':post})
        else:
            self.response.out.write('no post with this slug')
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you're hoping to accomplish? Click **edit** under your question and add the following:  (1) What you tried? (DONE) (2) What you are seeing? (DONE) and **(3) What you expect to see?** (This is the piece you're missing. You haven't told us what you *want* to happen.)

Comment: @jmort253 thanks for your response.  I've added more details in the question.

Comment: If you view the source of the blank page, do you see the text "no post with this slug"?  I wonder if perhaps your else is firing but you're just outputting something that isn't text/html? suppose you output to another HTML template? Like `self.render_template('notFound.html')`  BTW +1 for cleaning up your question! :)

Comment: Check your code in the question body. I see 2 versions. Indenting is important in Python, so am not sure what your code really looks like...

Comment: @jmort253 it now looks like the second block.  If you click on the invalid link above you see I no longer get an error, but no page is displayed and the source view is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this version of your code, you see the blank page because the for loop was never entered. Since the slug is not valid, results is null or empty. As a result, the if statement is never reached, which means neither the if nor the else will fire at all.

```
class ViewPost(BaseHandler):
def get(self, slug):
    post = Posts.all()
    post.filter('path =', slug)
    results = post.fetch(1)
    for post in results:
        path = post.path
        if path == slug:
            self.render_template('post.html', {'post':post})
        else:
            self.response.out.write('no post with this slug')
```

In this example, your indenting is set in a manner where the if statement is always reached, regardless of the slug. However, as in the above example, results is either empty or null. The for loop is never run, meaning your path variable is never set.

```
class ViewPost(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, slug):
        post = Posts.all()
        post.filter('path =', slug)
        results = post.fetch(1)
        for post in results:
            path = post.path
        if path == slug:
            self.render_template('post.html', {'post':post})
        else:
            self.response.out.write('no post with this slug')
```

This of course leads to the following error message when the comparison is attempted for `path == slug`:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'path' referenced before assignment

Basically, to solve this problem, you need to initialize path with a value so that it's not referenced without an assignment. Set path to a default value that is guaranteed to be different than your slugs, and if the slug doesn't lead to a valid record, then your else will fire.

**Solution:**

Example with `path = 'none``, and the indentation setup so that the if statement is always reached.

```
class ViewPost(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, slug):
        path = 'none'
        post = Posts.all()
        post.filter('path =', slug)
        results = post.fetch(1)
        for post in results:
            path = post.path
        if path == slug:
            self.render_template('post.html', {'post':post})
        else:
            self.response.out.write('no post with this slug')
```

Comment: Yep, it works.  You are amazing.  Thanks for your help.  Hope I can find a way to return the favor.